# How can I do the equivalent of tail -f with ls?

Tags: shell, pipe, ls, tail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to follow a command (run repeatedly)? as one would follow a file using tail -f?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16076/is-it-possible-to-follow-a-command-run-repeatedly-as-one-would-follow-a-file)

I would like to monitor files that are being downloaded to a directory in real time on screen in bash.

Is there an easy way in Linux to do the equivalent of `tail -f` but on a directory, perhaps using ls?

Comment: `watch -n1 ls`?

Comment: If you want to react to new files being created, what you need is [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use the "watch" command:

```
watch ls
```

This will run the "ls" command every 2 seconds.

Comment: This is the simplest answer that worked.  I wanted to add that -n# dictates how often to refresh. eg. watch -n1 ls - will run ls every second and refresh the data on screen.

Comment: [For my own notes as Google will bring me back here] On OSX you can do `while :; do clear; ls; sleep 2; done`

Answer (score 10):

`watch` is definitely the best answer if you've got it. But for completeness, you could simulate something crudely similar with a simple bit of shell-script:

```
while (true)
do
     date
     ls -lrt | tail -n 10
     sleep 2
     clear
done
```

Another way could be using `diff`. This one will also point out if files are removed that used to be present. An advantage is it doesn't clear the terminal, so you can see the complete record of all changes by scrolling up. A disadvantage is that it creates two temporary files to manage the state change reasoning.

```
ls1="/tmp/listing1.dat"
ls2="/tmp/listing2.dat"
ls -lrt > ${ls1}
ls -lrt > ${ls2}

while (true)
do
     diff ${ls1} ${ls2} | grep '[<>]'
     sleep 2
     cp ${ls2} ${ls1}
     ls -lrt > ${ls2}
done
```

Comment: Recovery boot does not have `watch` so this is handy.

Answer (score 5):

Check out `inotifywait`,

e.g to monitor folder `abc`, you could do:

```
while inotifywait -e close_write abc; do
   # do `ls` when abc changed
   ls abc
done
```

Comment: This will not run the `ls` until the download has completed (or at least it calls close() on the file). Still, +1 for using inotify.